# Val() Not working correctly or not how it should

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a "x" amount from the inputbox and use that value for value changing and the math does something weird and doesn't work correctly.

```
        Dim infantry As Integer
infantry = InputBox("How many do you want to attack with?", "Choose how many:", , ,)
frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text = (Val(frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text) - infantry * 2).ToString("N0")
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hInFp.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajfAq.jpg)

The inputted value was 1

Comment: `Val( "9,850,000")` is 9.0  but if you input `"1"` seems like the answer should be `7`.  Dont use `Val` - the 1980s are over.  Also turn on Option Strict to avoid similar errors.  `InputBox` returns a string, not an integer

Comment: don't use `Val` and parse correctly the input (`Convert.ToInt32` or `Integer.Parse` or `Integer.TryParse` or same for floating point numbers if they are better suited)

Comment: BTW its working as documented on [MSDN - Conversion.Val Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0(v=vs.110).aspx): `The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number.`  When something doesnt seem to work as it should, check your assumption(s)

Comment: @Sehnsucht I am new to VB so where would I put it?

Comment: @Plutonix Okay, I see what you are saying but what should I use then?

Comment: Don't use `VB6` methods, if you want to write `VB.NET` code!

Answer (score 0):

Inputbox() returns a string. You need to convert it to an integer value before you assign it to infantry. Also this function supports overloads so you don't have to include the arguments you don't plan to use.

```
infantry = CInt(InputBox("How many do you want to attack with?", "Choose how many:"))
```

This will return an error however if the value entered is non numeric. You would need to use a try/catch or preferably validate the result before using it:

```
        Dim infantry As Integer
    Dim Result As String = InputBox("How many do you want to attack with?", "Choose how many:")
    If IsNumeric(Result) Then infantry = CInt(Result) Else MsgBox("Enter a numeric value", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `Integer.TryParse` to get the inputted value (**TryParse** because we don't have control about what can be that value)
If the parsing is successful we retrieve the label value (using **Parse** because that value is under our control so should always be a valid int)
Finally we make the calculation and assign the label it's representation.

If the parsing fail we should handle that (error message, looping to get a new value, etc.)

For (possibly both) parsing you should take care of formatting and culture issues which will dictate what format is valid or not.

```
Dim input = InputBox("How many do you want to attack with?", "Choose how many:")
Dim infantry As Integer

If Integer.TryParse (input, infantry) Then
    Dim hpai = Integer.Parse (frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text = (hpai - infantry * 2).ToString("N0")
Else
    ' handle not an int inputted case
End If
```

Comment: Okay @Sehnsucht , I copied that whole code in and put in 1 and the lblHPAI stayed the same. No change.

Comment: @CaptainCaboose except the just corrected typo (two closing parens in InputBox line instead of one) this work just fine in my tests ; maybe telling what error occurs precisely could help

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input String was not in a correct format.

That was the error/ @Sehnsucht

Comment: @CaptainCaboose and what did you put in the InputBox ?

Comment: I put 1 in the box

Comment: Well, can't reproduce, with similar parameters I get `-1` in the label which is the expected result `1 - 1 * 2 = -1`

Comment: @Sehnuscht Can you put the label value to 9,000,000?

Comment: ah, that's lead us somewhere, I assumed some things about the formatting, my fault, I edit

Comment: So what should I do now? @Sehnuscht

Comment: I am getting a protected level for Number Styles and Culture Info. Should I declare them as Integer? @Sehnuscht

Comment: Sorry but I am a noobie at VB

Comment: I figured out the issue. It needed Globalization.NumberStyles. Thank you so much for all your help!!!!! Would you like me to tell you when the game is done? @Sehnuscht